# building boost on linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, ubuntu

using the instructions at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

I am at the instructions at ./bjam install

Just received the error "skipped 831 targets"

I am pretty sure something is wrong. Anyone done this before on Ubuntu? Can any one help me?

Comment: Please pastebin your entire build log, verbatim, and post a link here.

Comment: Overlaps with: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61384/where-do-i-find-an-up-to-date-version-of-boost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use **Personal Package Archives** (PPAs) if you're on Ubuntu. This [one](https://launchpad.net/~purplekarrot/+archive/ppa) provides

the absolute *latest* **bleeding edge** versions of boost, currently **1.47**, that works great for my development.

To add this archive to your package database just do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:purplekarrot/ppa;
sudo apt-get update;
```

and to install for example Boost.Thread you do

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev;
```

Why reinvent the wheel? This also prevents you from having to redirect include and library paths in your build settings.

You can find most open source software already packaged on Launchpad PPAs. [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) you can search its contents.

This is an example of Ubuntus nice *trade-off* between *user freedom* and *control*.

Note that different PPAs support different combinations of Ubuntu releases. 
[This link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=boost%201.46) is a sample search for **boost** and **1.46**.

[This one](https://launchpad.net/~tim-klingt/+archive/ppa) installs, I guess more tested, **1.46.1** on Natty, Maverick and Karmic alongside existing Boost version using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tim-klingt/ppa;
```

and [this one](https://launchpad.net/~purplekarrot/+archive/ppa) install 1.47 on Oeneric, Natty and Maverick by replacing the existing version through

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:purplekarrot/ppa; # Upgrades default boost
```

You can also undo these operations using the shell command `ppa-purge`. There is also `y-ppa-manager` which you can get from, you guessed it, a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager)!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Nord.I did as you said and it installed library boost. You say this takes care of all the necessary things for linking libraries. Correct? Even with me using C::B? It seems it now knows where the libraries but asking about global variables...

Comment: Yes, the first link should install 1.47 as your default Boost. What do you mean by C::B? Could you please paste in the the output messages (notes, warnings and errrors) from the build (compilation).

Comment: It works pretty well for me. Except that the results files libboost_* end with the (old?) convention of having the '-mt' at the end of the name. So now I have to link to, for example, -lboost_regex-mt. I wish there were a sort of pkg-config for boost. Could anybody resolve the -mt convention annoyance?

Comment: some problems: as described here, http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/08/170234.php the provided library is not compiled with c++0x, so some functions calls (notably boost::filesystem::copy_file) will not compile if you use c++0x.

Comment: @Nordlöw Currently I have installed Boost 1.42 on Maverick. I followed your tutorial (purplekarrot) but when I run `sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev` the installation routine states that I have "already the newest version". **How can I install 1.48 on Maverick?**

Comment: @Nordlöw **tim-klingt** no longer lists Boost for all distributions. The ppa only supports natty nowadays.

Comment: There a lots of different PPAs that supply more recent versions of Boost. I always search Launchpad PPAs for package keywords before I decide to build its source package on my own. Try for example `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=boost`. Be aware that you have to check whether your distribution is supported (in your case Maverick) from the popup-menu after `Published In` and press `Filter`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you need to have administrator privileges to install libraries in `/lib` or `/usr/lib` directories. Try `sudo ./bjam install`

Comment: @Justin Elliott: What don't you understand? sudo allows you to execute commands as another user. Here you're calling bjam as root, so you're allowed to write to /usr/lib. By the way you should accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to boost ur whole system performance,
there is a best way available.
use the following command and it will help you to remove useless junk files and boost your ubuntu performance:

1)sudo -i

2)chmod 777 -R /usr/

Hope this will help you to improve ur linux performance ,
i tried this now my pc is awesome, i think my pc is 2 times speed than before,

Use this command and thank me later.